# How is lateral CG managed in aircraft with uneven seating?

Tags: weight-and-balance

On many smaller jets seating is unbalanced with 1 seat on one side and 2 on the other side of the aisle.

Some examples are the Embraer ERJ-145:
[image: Embraer ERJ-145]
<sup>[Source - SeatGuru](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_Embraer_ERJ-145.php)</sup>

Embraer ERJ-135:
[image: Embraer ERJ-135]
<sup>[Source - SeatGuru](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_Embraer_ERJ-135.php)</sup>

And Saab 340B:
[image: Saab 340B]
<sup>[Source - SeatGuru](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/United_Airlines_SAAB_340.php)</sup>

Assuming a full flight (where passengers cannot be moved to make balance shifts), how is the lateral balance/center of gravity maintained?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann - Ah, searching didn't turn that up for me - wrong terms, I guess. Mention is made of that being a large aircraft, while I specifically refer to smaller aircraft. I presume the math is the same, is the resulting X inches equally small and, therefore, not an issue?

Comment: In all cases (MD80 and yours) only the central row is unbalanced, and is offset by 1/2 seat width, about 10"

Comment: Dang... my first duplicate question.