# Passenger cabin asymmetric seating and balance

Tags: weight-and-balance, cabin-design

In the early 1990s I made many short haul flights in Short 360 aircraft. These had passenger seats set up as two rows on the right, one row on the left as per the picture.

Assuming a full load of passengers, what are the implications if any of having more weight on one side and if there are implications how would they address it ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the MD-80 seat layout affect the balance of the aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25178/does-the-md-80-seat-layout-affect-the-balance-of-the-aircraft) And the more general question: [How is lateral CG managed in aircraft with uneven seating?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32314/14897)

Comment: Yes indeed thanks, post as an answer and I'll tick it.

Comment: The certification requirement for control authority at lateral CG limits is only that the airplane have sufficient roll authority to trim to hands off level flight with the CG at the lateral offset limit, in the most critical case (usually single engine at V2+10).  You actually have a lot of room to play with.